# How to pass parameters into an ssrs report without using query string

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on a report in which the input parameter is an array and it should allow any number of values in array. If I pass the parameter as query string, there is a limit for the length of query string right? whether there is any other method to pass parameters into the ssrs report.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a good way, but you can store parameters in a table and pass an indicator of parameter set to report. It is a way of reading a secondary dataset in the report

Comment: I wrote a blog specifically about how to pass parameteres to an SSRS report using the URL as an array... yes there are limits to a URL string, so beware... http://webniggles.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/how-to-pass-list-of-parameters-from.html